# Rails 4 ajax not refreshing after hitting submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, crud

I am using AJAX to render my items partial so that I can create a new item directly in the index page.

Right now the form sort of works. I can create an item and it will get added to the database, but in order to see the change on the index page I have to hit refresh.

I can destroy really easy straight from the index page here is the code for that. I did try and rework this destroy to instead create, but that was unsuccessful.

Any suggestions would be great. I am trying to keep the code fairly simple like the destroy function.

destroy.js.erb

```
$('.delete_item').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
        $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
});
```

Here is my index.html. This is just the basic rails styling.

```
<h1>Listing items</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th>Done</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item.content %></td>
        <td><%= item.done %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', item %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true, class: 'delete_item' %> </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<div class='new-item'>
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>
```

create.js.erb

```
$('.new-item').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items/form', locals: {item: @item}) %>");
```

Items Controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html, :js

  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    @items = Item.all
    @item = Item.new #will rename later to @new_item
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json 
      format.js 
    end
  end

  # GET /items/1
  # GET /items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /items/new
  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  # GET /items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  # DELETE /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js   { render layout: false }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:content, :done)
    end
end
```

Console log:

```
Started POST "/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-04 15:35:55 -0500
Processing by ItemsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "item"=>{"content"=>"Eggs", "done"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Item"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("content", "created_at", "done", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "Eggs"], ["created_at", "2014-10-04 20:35:55.965462"], ["done", "f"], ["updated_at", "2014-10-04 20:35:55.965462"]]
   (185.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/items/17
Completed 302 Found in 196ms (ActiveRecord: 186.3ms)


Started GET "/items/17" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-04 15:35:56 -0500
Processing by ItemsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"17"}
  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  Rendered items/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 59.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Edit 1: Based off suggestion. The item still only showing after refresh.

```
    def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = "Item was saved"
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error. Please try again."
    end
    respond_with(@item) do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to @item}
    end
  end
```

Edit 2: Still not working, but some changes
create.js.erb

```
  $('.list-items').prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(@item)) %>");
   $('.new-item').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'form', locals: { item: @item }) %>)");
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class='list-items'>
  <%= render 'items', collection: @items%>
</div>


<div class='new-item'>
  <%= render 'form'%>
</div>
```

Comment: try saving the ```@item.save``` outside the respond_to block and then just with respond_with for @item to render for ```format.html``` as a redirect option.

Comment: Check out my edit above. I made the changes but it is still only showing on refresh.

Comment: Before your change to `create.js.erb`, I would have said that that was the problem. You were emptying the form but not appending the item to the list. Now your JS seems to be doing that (well, pre-pending). To debug, I'd add a `console.log("<%= @item.inspect %>")` or something in that file, to see if it's being hit at all. That will output in the _Web Inspector_ console (ie not in the server logs that you showed above under the title "console log"). If that's getting hit, then I'd try to make sure that your JS works when typed into the WI console. That should help you narrow down what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Remove  `$('.list-items').prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(@item)) %>");` in your `create.js.erb` then add an ID to your table like `<table id="myTable">`

In your controller

```
def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = "Item was saved"
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error. Please try again."
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to @item}
      format.js {render :inline => "<tr><td><%= @item.content %></td><td><%= @item.done %></td><td><%= link_to 'Show', @item %></td><td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %></td><td><%= link_to 'Destroy', @item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true, class: 'delete_item' %></td></tr>"}
    end
end
```

In your application.js (or controller_name.js) in assets/javascripts folder

```
$(".list-items").on("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
    $('#myTable tbody).append(xhr.responseText);    
});
```

Don't forget `:remote => true` inside the `form_for` tag of your form